# How to build web in Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to build web app using Ionic 5
I have tried:

```
ionic cordova build browser --prod --release
```

and

```
ionic serve --prod
```

both failed and have error like:

```
1. If 'ion-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1. If 'ion-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the'@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

'ion-label' is 
not a known element:
1. If 'ion-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

It seems that when building production, it doesnot regconize ionic component.

I am fine when I use following command:

```
ionic serve
```

so how to deal with it?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The command for building ionic code for web is `ionic build`.

If you want to build the code for production then use - `ionic build --prod`.

This is build all of the Ionic code into `www` folder which you can use it serve with `nginx` or any other web server.

Comment: still get the same error when using 'ionic build --prod', which it cannot recognize ionic component. However I can build using 'ionic build'. It seems when building production, it can't build with ionic?

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with the `--prod` flag. 
Can you paste the complete error stack here when you add the `--prod` flag?

Comment: there is so many error so I can only show some of them, the main reason is it don't know ionic component, something like:
'ion-label' is 
not a known element:
1. If 'ion-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

and all <ion-*> have those error

Comment: There must be something wrong with the ionic core module.
Can you update the question with the package.json and appmodule code?

Comment: I can't paste whole package.json as stackoverflow complains my question is mainly code and it doesn't allow to post

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming here in the future, one big difference between

```
ionic build
```

compared to

```
ionic build --prod
```

is that the compiler will validate the code in way more detail.

I used to run into these issues on my last Ionic app so much that I never built with the production flag because I didn't understand.

Now with my new Ionic app I've realized the problem was with my code.

In the case of the question above, I'd say the developer is missing some dependencies that were supposed to be imported into NgModule. Especially if they are using lazy loading they might be missing the import on that specific page module.

For example, on Ionic 5/6 the pageName.module.ts file must include the IonicModule like this example:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { PageNameRoutingModule } from './pageName-routing.module';

import { PageName } from './pageName.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    PageNameRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [PageName]
})
export class PageNameRoutingModule {}
```

The best way to avoid this is to use the following CLI command when creating a new page:

```
ionic generate page pageName
```

There is also another situation where you can get these sorts of errors when all imports are correct. It can happen if you are trying to incorrectly use the ionic component. For example if you are using a component that doesn't exist or you are trying to attach some sort of function that is incompatible with that ionic component. These errors will normally show up in build without the production flag but maybe not.

Always refer to https://ionicframework.com/docs/components for proper use of the Ionic components.